# Next 13 Jest test fails using 'next/headers'

Tags: next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, next.js13

I am using Next.JS 13, and have a component which is using

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
```

The simplified component:

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

function Simple() {
  console.log({ cookies });
  return <div>Simple</div>;
}

export default Simple;
```

and the simplified test:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import Simple from './Simple';

describe('<Simple />', () => {
  it('should render Simple component', () => {
    render(<Simple />);
  });
});
```

When I have any reference to the `cookies`, in this case

```js
  console.log({ cookies });
```

I always get the following error when running jest tests:

```
     x NEXT_RSC_ERR_CLIENT_IMPORT: next/headers
       ,-[1:1]
     1 | import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
       : ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     2 | 
     3 | function Simple() {
     4 |   console.log({ cookies });
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

I have tried mocking the 'next/headers' with jest.mock, like so, but to no avail:

```js
jest.mock('next/headers', () => ({
  cookies: jest.fn(),
}));
```

My `jest.config.js`

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
});

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./.jest/setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};

module.exports = async () => ({
  ...(await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)()),
});
```

My `./jest/setup.js`

```js
require('jest-fetch-mock').enableMocks();

import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Package versions

```json
    "next": "13.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have observed that the issue stems from the `next/jest` setup, where [`SWC`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/testing#jest-and-react-testing-library) is used as the transform. Therefore made couple of changes:

Added new `jest.config.js` file with the following configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest/setup.js"],
    testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": ["babel-jest", { presets: ["next/babel"] }],
    },
};
```

The purpose of this new configuration file is to replace SWC with Babel for transforming JS, JSX, TS, and TSX files.

Added `server-only.js` file to mock directory to simulate the server components. This mock prevents the error from being thrown.

```js
module.exports = {};
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/njk112/next-js-rsc-testing/main) or [github repo](https://github.com/njk112/next-js-rsc-testing) for example

Answer (score 0):

The error 'NEXT_RSC_ERR_CLIENT_IMPORT: next/headers' implies that you are trying to use cookies within a client component. the next/headers library only works within a dynamic react server component, route handler or server actions.

See the reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies